# Как выбрать случайный элемент из массива C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Так вот. Массив состоит из GameObject я хочу как то выбрать случайный элемент из него и присвоить в другую переменную. Заранее спасибо каждому кто отзовётся

Comment: `var obj = array[Random.Range(array.Length)];`

Comment: Спасибо, сделал. Всем тем кто тоже будет искать решение в добавок коммента (может aepot у себя поправит). Нужно "var obj = array[Random.Range(0, array.Length)];" Там тип надо минимальное значение и максимальное. Всем Удачи <3

Answer (score 1):

Присвой объект по индексу остатка от деления случайного числа на размер массива. Примерный алгоритм:

```
int index = rand() % arr.size();  
var destination = arr[index];
```

Comment: это немного не Unity код